# replace special characters using unicode

Tags: python, regex, unicode

how can i replace the double quotation marks with the stylistically correct quotation marks („ U+201e or “ U+201c ) according to German spelling.

example:

zitat = 'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt"'

I've tried the code

```
import re
zitatnew = re.sub(r'"', r'[u+201e]', zitat)
print(zitatnew)

Laut Durkheim ist ein [u+201e]soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt[u+201e]
```

How can i replace the double quotations marks with the correct one using unicode?

Maybe one of you can help me.
P.S. I'm sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate while there are `"` in the string and in every iteration replace one pair of quotes:

```python
zitat = 'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt"'

print(f"Before replace: {zitat}")

while "\"" in zitat:
    zitat = zitat.replace("\"", "\u201e", 1)
    zitat = zitat.replace("\"", "\u201c", 1)

print(f"After replace: {zitat}")
```

The `1` as third argument in `replace()` is important to replace only the first ocurrence of the `"`. This should give a correct output for any string with an even number of `"`.

Output:

```
Before replace: Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt"
After replace: Laut Durkheim ist ein „soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt“
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this

```
re.sub(r'"', u"\u201E", zitat)
```

or the more appropriate

```
s = 'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt"'
# substitute the opening quote
output = re.sub('\B"', u"\u201C", s)
# substitute the closing quote as well
output = re.sub('"\B', u"\u201D", output)

>>> output
'Laut Durkheim ist ein “soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt”'
```

which gives

> 'Laut Durkheim ist ein “soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt”'

Comment: Following on from this answer: If you would like to get the correct "opening" and "closing" quotes, depending on whether your original quote follows either some white space or starts at a new line, or it is at the end of a line or followed by punctuation or white space, you could use the following 2 commands: `zitatnew = re.sub('(\s)"|^"', u"\\1\u201C", zitat)` followed by `zitatnew = re.sub('"([\s\.\?!])|"$', u"\u201D\\1", zitatnew)`. In your example this would give: Laut Durkheim ist ein “soziologischer Tatbestand jede mehr oder weniger [...] unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt”

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` is more efficient than replacing over and over, and with a replacement function it can be done in one pass:

---

```py
import re
s = '"this" "is" "a" "test" "string"'
s = re.sub(r'(\b")|("\b)',lambda m: '\u201c' if m.group(1) else '\u201e',s)
print(s)
```

```
„this“ „is“ „a“ „test“ „string“
```